# Converting wsdl into java classes using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I have a wsdl file which i converted into java classes in Eclipse Kepler, using the solution provided by this question : [wsdl into java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460571/how-do-you-convert-wsdl-to-java-classes-using-eclipse)

However i cannot find the java classes...Maybe i'm looking in the wrong place. Any help please?

Comment: can you search your hard disk for *.java files?

Comment: You cannot get the exact web service classes as production by any methods. You can get mirror services, and you should implement the logic.