# How can i generate java classes using jaxb from a wsdl file?

Tags: java, jaxb

i am having a wsdl file that defines the soap webservice . I also have java 8 installed in my machine 
How can i generate java classes using JAXB

really appreciate any help

Comment: Have a look at this post, it is pretty straight forward. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460571/how-do-you-convert-wsdls-to-java-classes-using-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*PROJECT_PACKAGE* - Package

*FILE* - File name

*DIRECTORY_PATH* - Extraction Path (folder)

Enter the following command at the terminal:

```
xjc -p PROJECT_PACKAGE FILE.xsd -d DIRECTORY_PATH
```

E.g. this:

```
xjc -p test.jaxb user.xsd -d teste
```

will generate the following path:

```
teste/test/jaxb/*.java
```