# Create a the .jar of a Web Service from a WSDL

Tags: java, jar, wsdl

How can I create a file .jar from a WSDL to create a web service in java?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You can not do this. A WSDL only describes the interface of the webservice. You need to implement it on your own. You can use a framework to generate the needed java interfaces from your WSDL. You need to do some research and then pick a framework that fits your needs.

Comment: is there some tool that can create the java class from my wsdl?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460571/how-do-you-convert-wsdls-to-java-classes-using-eclipse

Comment: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is old post, but may be useful for someone in future. I did something like this & works fine for me -

```
Created 'lib' dir parallel to 'src'
$ pwd
<root dir>/lib
$ wsimport <address report wsdl url> -verbose
$ jar cvf address-report.jar .

#My project is gradle project, added dependency 'build.gradle'
dependencies {
    implementation files('lib/address-report.jar')
}
```