# How to convert wsdl file to java file

Tags: java, wsdl

I am trying to convert a WSDL file into a Java file. How can I do this? I have a WSDL file in a folder. I want to convert that WSDL file to a Java file.

Comment: have a look at Apache CXF

Comment: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert WSDLs to Java classes using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460571/how-do-you-convert-wsdls-to-java-classes-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

JDK 8 had wsimport, which is removed in later versions. So if you are using Java 8, that is an option available.

Some links:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/wsimport.html
https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Another option is to use Apache CXF:
https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

And you can use SoapUI to generate the the client, assuming the requirement is to generate java client.