# Generate classes with SOAPMessage

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Hellow. Can i generate classes from a web service in my java project using SOAPMessage?. [This is the WS](https://www.crcind.com/csp/samples/SOAP.Demo.cls?wsdl) and I want generate the classes that are here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can different tools for generating Java classes from WSDL file.

[Generate WSDL Stubs with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wsdl-stubs) uses wsimport Maven plugin

[How do you convert WSDLs to Java classes using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460571/how-do-you-convert-wsdls-to-java-classes-using-eclipse)

[Generate Java Code from WSDL dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html), in case you are using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works if i have the WSDL file, but how can i generate classes if i don't have the WSDL file? Because i tried that and don't works

Comment: Give the WSDL endpoint address. The link that you have mentioned in your question.