# Generate stubs from WSDL using jdk 17 and gradle 7.6

Tags: java, web-services, gradle, soap, java-17

I got the wsdl from client and need to generate stubs from that wsdl but condition is it should be **using jdk 17 and gradle 7.6. **

Tried multiple ways but always face issue with jars compatibility which is working in the older java version.

I am expecting build.gradle file which read the wsdl file and generate java objects in build/generated folder using jdk 17

Comment: hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please share the solution which you have tried to resolve your issue. Please share what problems (error code, error message), which you have encountered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate java from wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73005780/generate-java-from-wsdl)