# Unable to convert WSDL url to JAVA

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a Spring Boot project. I have a 3rd party to use its service. It provides me WSDL url but I really new to the WSDL.
I've found that if I want to connect its service I need to convert WSDL to the JAVA class.

So, I've found 2 solutions to do this.

1. Using "wsimport -keep -verbose [http://compA.com/ws/server?wsdl"](http://compA.com/ws/server?wsdl%22)

refer: https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

When I attempt on this method I get below error.

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime
> that supports wsimport. Please visit http://www.java.com for
> information on installing Java.

Here is my **java --version**

> java 19.0.1 2022-10-18
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode,
> sharing)

2. Using Eclipse

According to [How do you convert WSDLs to Java classes using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460571/how-do-you-convert-wsdls-to-java-classes-using-eclipse), my Eclipse has no **Web Services** option to be selected even I download Eclipse from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-09/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following steps:

- put the WSDL in my repo anyway to see later changes
- create a maven or gradle task to have the "WSDL to java generation" with JAXB whenever I will need it: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/#initial
- extend from `WebServiceGatewaySupport` to have a client

You could also follow this complete example:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/